# history.push and Link change the URL and not re render the component if I have many routes for the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
// the routes here
<Switch>
     <Route exact path='/:page' component={Dashboard} />

      <Route exact path='/:subCateg/:categ' component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

I want to go from the first route to the second one, if I used (history.push) or (Link) just the URL change and not reloading.

Also, the same problem if I want to go from the second route to itself but with new params.

```
//here I'm in Dashbord and the History also pushing to Dashboard
onClick={
        ()=>{
            history.push({pathname:`/${categ}/${subCateg}`, state: {id: subCateg.id}})
                                    // window.location.reload(false);
            }
        }
```

as you can see I userd "window.location.reload(false);" and it solved the loading problem, but what if I want to Goback by browser Goback button, the same problem : change URL & not relaoding.
also I think using "window.location.reload(false);" is not a good practice.

``
package.json: 
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",

Comment: Can you please share if you are in the same component (`Dashboard`) then why you are dealing with passing values through the route instead of introducing state somehow in that component? Maybe I miss something here. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am in the same component (Dashboard) and it is reusable, so I want to use it with more than one route, but I want new data each time I render Dashboard with each route, so I decided to use history.push() to push to a new route and to send the data I need

Answer (score 0):

As you are using react-router-dom you should not be using history.push(). Try to use Redirect from react-router-dom instead.

Just use a state named redirect and set it to the new route you want to go with your function:

```
onClick={() => this.setState({ redirect: 'newpath' }};
```

Then just put a return inside your render just like this:

```
if (this.state.redirect) {
    return <Redirect to={this.state.redirect} />;
}
return (
    ...rest of your render
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
 tried this solution, it gives me the same result: push to route without reload and there is a problem in (go back & go forward button in the browser) when I click Go Back it doesn't take me back.
Anyway I want to send data when redirect and not sure if Redirect can do that

Answer (score 0):

Caveat:  I'm dangerously new to React as well as much around it, but have been pulling my hair out on this for the last day myself.  So there are a number of reasons this may be very bad advice.  But this was my situation and how I got it to work.

```
function newSongRedirect() {
    history.push("/SongDetail/0");
    history.go(0);
}
```

and hook it up to my button:

```
<button onClick={() => newSongRedirect() } >New Song</button>
```

It appears that history.push adds the value to the history, but doesn't cause it to be acted on.  As now the first item, `history.go(0)` then causes it to act on it.

I've seen some posts referencing that history.push can't be used if you're nested in a `<BrowserRouter>`, but in my case, attempting to replace that in my index.js just led to other issues.

Also, I found [this post](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/) from what looks to be part of the team working on react router.  It seems the useHistory hook will be replaced when they get a chance.

> Heads up: The useHistory hook is a quick stopgap for a future hook that we are working on: useNavigate. useNavigate will provide an API that is more closely aligned with  and will fix a few long-standing problems with using the history API directly in the router (it'll probably look a lot like @reach/router's navigate API). We are providing useHistory for now to make the migration of existing code that uses the history API as painless as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
actually adding history.go(0); it was exactly like adding  "window.location.reload(false);"
it solved the reloading problem but still, the main problem which is:  what if I want to go back by clicking Go Back button in the browser? the same problem: changing URL&not reloading